# Execute certain logic till it meets the requirement

Tags: c#, .net, api, recursion, windows-services

I have written a `C#` code to pull the data from vendor API, Here I can pull only up to 100 records in per API request. If there are more than 100 records present/returned from the API then the API will return `"paging"` information appended it in the form of Next URL attribute like below in the `JSON` response data;

```
 ],
    "paging": {
        "next": {
            "after": "2459708154",
            "link": "https://api.someapi.com/objects?archived=false&limit=100&after=2459708154
        },
        "prev": null
    }
```

My concern here is that I want to write a recursive code logic which will check the returned `JSON` response data and if it contains the `"paging"` attribute appended in the response then it call the API again till it reaches to the final request call where the `"paging"` attribute data will not appended/returned in the `JSON` response or it will be null.

Currently I am doing this using multiple `If` statements and pulling data only till the 300-400 records for now like below;

```
var recentDealsInfo = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, isGetRecentAPI: true);
//store response in a list of deals
List<Deal> lstRecentDeals = recentDealsInfo.results;
//handle paging for more than 100 records
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recentDealsInfo.paging.next.after))
{
    //build request url using paging information for next 100 records
    var nxtdeals = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, nxtLink: recentDealsInfo.paging.next.after, isGetRecentAPI: true);
    //add records to the list
    lstRecentDeals.AddRange(nxtdeals.results);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nxtdeals.paging.next.after))
    {
        //build request url using paging information for next 100 records
        var nextdeals = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, nxtLink: nxtdeals.paging.next.after, isGetRecentAPI: true);
        //add records to the list
        lstRecentDeals.AddRange(nextdeals.results);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextdeals.paging.next.after))
        {
            //build request url using paging information for next 100 records
            var nextdeal = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, nxtLink: nextdeals.paging.next.after, isGetRecentAPI: true);
            //add records to the list
            lstRecentDeals.AddRange(nextdeal.results);
        }
        // and so on ....
    }                    
}
```

Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Why recursion? That sounds like you could solve this with a `while (paged)` loop? Or even `do .. while`

Comment: @BiesiGrr - I am looking for suggestions, could you please advise how this scenario can be handled using `while()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving this using a `while` loop could look like this

```
var response = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, isGetRecentAPI: true);
List<Deal> recentDeals = response.results;
string nextPage = response.paging.next.after;

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPage))
{
    response = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, nxtLink: nextPage, isGetRecentAPI: true);
    recentDeals.AddRange(response.results);
    nextPage = response.paging.next.after;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var recentDealsInfo = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, isGetRecentAPI: true);

//store response in a list of deals
List<Deal> lstRecentDeals = recentDealsInfo.results;

var after = recentDealsInfo.paging.next.after;

//handle paging for more than 100 records
while (true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(after))
    {
        break;
    }
    
    //build request url using paging information for next 100 records
    var tmp = await _objReq.Post<Deals>(_limit, dtPastDay, nxtLink: after, isGetRecentAPI: true);
    lstRecentDeals.AddRange(tmp.results);
    
    after = tmp.paging.next.after;
}
```